# How to read and write data in Microsoft excel 2010 in python

Tags: python-2.7, xlrd, openpyxl, xlwt, xlutils

Steps what I have done

1.Reading input data from xlsx file

2.calculated week number and total hours done by each department

Need to do:

1.Reading particular row column from another existing xlsx sheet

2.writing total hours for each department in existing xlsx sheet

I am using xlutils but format of xlsx file has been corrupted,which library i should use for this?

Comment: The documentation makes it clear that xlutils cannot edit XLSX files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
http://www.python-excel.org/
, the best library to read/write Excel 2010 files is `openpyxl`.